# How do i use a ng-repeat with different classes with each index

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am building a timeline and i want to invert every other index in the ng-repeat. I used ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end on two separate divs but all they do is just repeat the same array twice.

```
<ul class="timeline">
    <li ng-repeat-start="t in vm.patientTimeLine">
        <div class="timeline-badge" style="background-color:#f9f9f9!important;"><i class="fa fa-phone hg-blue" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="card-block">
                 <h4 class="card-title"> {{t.FirstName}}'s reply was: <b ng-if="t.ReplyMessage !== null" class="stop">{{t.ReplyMessage}}</b></h4>
            </div>
     </li>

     <li class="timeline-inverted" ng-repeat-end>
        <div class="timeline-badge" style="background-color:#f9f9f9!important;"><i class="fa fa-phone hg-blue" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
           <div class="card-block">
               <h4 class="card-title"> {{t.FirstName}}'s reply was: <b ng-if="t.ReplyMessage !== null" class="stop">{{t.ReplyMessage}}</b></h4>
           </div>
     </li>
</ul>
```

I expect it to show the same list once but with the different css classes (timeline and timeline-inverted).

I thank you guys in advance.

Comment: If you've found any of these answers helpful, please select one as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to lets say, make timeline-inverted every other row, you can always use the varaibles ngRepeat provides.
For example:

```
$even   boolean     true if the iterator position $index is even (otherwise false).
```

List of variables can be found here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 1):

vicbyte's answer is correct, but I wanted to add a little more context.

ng-class can be used to conditionally apply classes with the items in ng-repeat.

```
<li ng-repeat="i in items" ng-class="{ 'inverted': $even }"></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$index` and potentially do an

```
ng-class="{'timeline': $even, 'timeline-inverted': $odd}"
```

The better option (in my opinion) is to use css classes "nth-child" to alter classes using css. Check out [W3Schools nth-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) to find it. I'm new to stack overflow so I'm not sure how to use JSFiddle but you could potentially use:

```
.timeline-inverted :nth-child(even) // Even Elements

.timeline-inverted :nth-child(odd) // Odd Elements
```

I'm unsure where you want to apply the class but if you wanted to change the class of a div element with your ngRepeat, you can do the following:

```
.timeline-inverted div:nth-child(even)
.timeline-inverted div:nth-child(odd)
```

Hopefully this answers your question.